# Painel Flutuante

Tags: android

A tela principal do cadastro de nosso sistema é bastante extensa, portanto o usuário precisa de vários scrolls até chegar à ultima linha do cadastro.

Coloquei no final do layout os botões de salvar, cancelar e outros, de fato, é um horizontal scroll onde ele tem acesso à vários outras opções.

Desse modo o usuário precisa de navegar até a parte inferior da tela para clicar nos botões.

Se eu colocasse na parte superior e ele tivesse que preencher a ultima linha, ele teria de voltar até em cima.

Uma vez que nem todos os campos são obrigatórios eu não sei quando ele estará pronto para gravar ou cancelar.

Pensei que a solução seria um painel flutuante com essa barra de tarefas que ficasse visível o tempo todo, estando ele em qualquer ponto da tela principal.

Outra opção seria eu colocar um menu. Desse modo ele poderia acessar quando quisesse. Gosto da barra flutuante por desafio e porque parece mais atraente, mas...

Alguém tem uma ideia ou link para me colocar no rumo certo.

Comment: Se calhar não entendi bem, por que não deixa esses botões fora do *scroll* de forma a ficarem fixos na parte debaixo da tela?

Comment: @ramaral Eu coloquei na parte de cima do Scroll o logo da Empresa e na Parte de baixo informações de direitos. E uso a parte do meio para inserir um ou outro fragmento de acordo com a tela que o usuário esta. Já tentei isso de colocar no fragmento da tela principal a parte scroll e a parte fixa, mas complicou demais e achei que estava indo pelo caminho errado.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Você quer algo semelhante à barra superior do Facebook apenas com o botão "Salvar", na parte inferior?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Não apenas com o botão Salvar. Porque ele pode precisar de outra ação. Na "barra de ferramentas" atual eu tenho 6 botões. Mas sim, seria algo parecido com aquela barra superior do Face.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Seis? Isso é muita coisa. Provavelmente não é uma boa ideia colocar isso numa barra só. Sugiro voltar à ideia de deixar na barra superior, pois você pode ocultar ou exibir mais opções de acordo com o tamanho/orientação da tela, tirando o máximo proveito do espaço disponível.

Comment: Uma outra sugestão seria trabalhar com um [`Action Overflow`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/design/patterns/actionbar.html) na sua AppBar ou Toolbar com todas essas opções. Acho que mesmo que seja uma barra fixa fora do scroll, seja muito ruim colocar tanta informação ali junta, e sendo próxima da Navigation Bar, talvez o usuário clique sem querer em algum botão e saia da tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma saída interresante seja o FloatingActionButton que é muito simples de implementar http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for varios botões você pode usar
o https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton pode ser uma opção bem interessante

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]