# Como fazer um Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para Android, gostaria de saber ou de algum exemplo para incluir um Floating Action Button?

Esse botão Floating Action Button, seria um atalho para uma ação no sistema, no meu caso, iria chamar uma activity. Esse botão teria um comportamento parecido com o *app* do Youtube, que contém esse botão/atalho da câmera do celular.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Opa, boa tarde. Tem um print de algum exemplo visual desse botão? Seria o Float Action Button? (http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/android-floating-action-button-2.png)

Comment: Antônio, exatamente isso, realmente não sabia o nome desse botão, procurava como widget mas não encontrava nada do que eu queria. Sabe qual a versão minima de suporte para esse botão? Obrigado Antônio!

Comment: Você diz criar um componente que dê para adicionar a tela inicial, por exemplo... Como existe para previsão do tempo etc..??

Comment: Marco, não, seria um **Float Action Button** mesmo, como disse, realmente não sabia como se chamava esse botão que ficava flutuando sobre as telas, pensei que fosse um widget, mas estava errado.

Comment: Opa, boa tarde. O botão então seria o FAB (Float Action Button) e pra criá-lo tem um tutorial bem legal aqui: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/03/how-to-make-floating-action-button-fab.html

Comment: Veja exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125807/painel-flutuante

Comment: Fiz uma edição à sua pergunta para incluir os novos detalhes, pode fazer também você sempre que perguntar. Se não gostar pode reverter para a edição anterior.

Answer (score 3):

#### FloatingActionButton

Há um guia para a utilização da biblioteca que lhe explica como e quando utilizar o botão flutuante de forma correta em projetos novos ou já existentes.

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_hoje_eh_sexta_feira" />
```

Bibliotecas de dependências

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

> O Google lançou uma ferramenta de suporte durante a Conferência do
>   Google I/O 2015.

#### FloatingActionButton Animado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifique o [Floating Action Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) do [Material Design](https://material.google.com/) do próprio Google.